# Ajax - Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am stuck on ajax error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
```

My Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$.get("http://agenda.myvnc.com:8895/datasnap/rest/TsrvServerMetodos/ag_get_convJson", null, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field + " ");
        });
     },"jsonp");
});
```

The result from url is:

```
{"result":[[{"indice":1002,"nome":"ABET"},{"indice":75,"nome":"ALLIANZ"},{"indice":1013,"nome":"AMAFRERJ"},{"indice":127,"nome":"AMBEP"},{"indice":1012,"nome":"AMIL"},{"indice":185,"nome":"AMIL POR ADMINISTRA\u00C7\u00C3O"},{"indice":1007,"nome":"ASES"},{"indice":108,"nome":"ASSEFAZ"},{"indice":1015,"nome":"ASSIM"},{"indice":1025,"nome":"ASSIM PREFEITURA"},{"indice":197,"nome":"BNDES-FAPES"},{"indice":31,"nome":"BRADESCO (B)"},{"indice":148,"nome":"BRASIL  ASSIST\u00CANCIA"},{"indice":9,"nome":"CABERJ ( B)"},{"indice":141,"nome":"CARE PLUS"},{"indice":1014,"nome":"CASSI"},{"indice":194,"nome":"CAURJ"},{"indice":12,"nome":"CNEN ( R)"},{"indice":1016,"nome":"COLIGA\u00C7\u00C3O POLICIA"},{"indice":1003,"nome":"CONMEDH"},{"indice":140,"nome":"CORREIOS"},{"indice":1018,"nome":"DIX"},{"indice":93,"nome":"ELETRONUCLEAR ( R)"},{"indice":16,"nome":"EMBRATEL ( B)"},{"indice":1004,"nome":"FUNCEF"},{"indice":18,"nome":"FURNAS"},{"indice":1010,"nome":"GAMA ESCOLAR"},{"indice":207,"nome":"GAMA SAUDE"},{"indice":21,"nome":"GOLDEN CROSS ( B)"},{"indice":1005,"nome":"HOSPITAL DO ROCHA"},{"indice":129,"nome":"INB (P)"},{"indice":1006,"nome":"INTEGRAL S\u00C1UDE"},{"indice":1008,"nome":"INTERM\u00C9DICA"},{"indice":24,"nome":"IRB"},{"indice":213,"nome":"LIFE EMPRESARIAL"},{"indice":201,"nome":"MAYER SISTEMA DE SAUDE"},{"indice":149,"nome":"MEDIAL SA\u00DADE ( R)"},{"indice":25,"nome":"MEDISERVICE ( B)"},{"indice":74,"nome":"MUTUA ( R)"},{"indice":187,"nome":"N\u00DACLEOS"},{"indice":67,"nome":"NUCLEP (R)"},{"indice":26,"nome":"PARTICULAR"},{"indice":27,"nome":"PETROBRAS PETRO ( B)"},{"indice":28,"nome":"PETROBRAS\\ DISTR ( R)"},{"indice":103,"nome":"PORTO SEGURO ( R)"},{"indice":193,"nome":"REAL GRANDEZA"},{"indice":175,"nome":"SALUTAR SA\u00DADE"},{"indice":32,"nome":"SEGURO CANADA ( B)"},{"indice":1011,"nome":"SIND SA\u00DADE"},{"indice":122,"nome":"SOCIOS COTISTAS"},{"indice":35,"nome":"SUL AMERICA ( B)"},{"indice":1,"nome":"Tabelas Originais"},{"indice":69,"nome":"UNAFISCO"},{"indice":1017,"nome":"UNIBANCO\/TEMPO SAUDE"},{"indice":1022,"nome":"UNIMED (FABIO)"},{"indice":1021,"nome":"UNIMED (GUALBERTO)"},{"indice":1024,"nome":"UNIMED (MARCIO)"},{"indice":1020,"nome":"UNIMED (RAFAEL)"},{"indice":1019,"nome":"UNIMED (SCOFANO)"},{"indice":1023,"nome":"UNIMED (TATIANA)"},{"indice":1001,"nome":"UNIMED CL\u00CDNICA"},{"indice":44,"nome":"URMES URGENCIAS ( R)"},{"indice":135,"nome":"VISITANTES"}]]}
```

here is the fiddle code link:
http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2254/

Comment: That is not JSONP: probably the remote server does not support it.

Comment: You have two issues. Firstly, the response is JSON, not JSONP so you should change the expected response type as JSON and JSONP are not interchangeable. Secondly, when you do that you get this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` This means that the third-party domain you're calling does not include CORS headers in the response, so cross-domain requests cannot be made to it through client side JS code. You will have to make the request from the server instead. See the question I marked as a duplicate for more information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm gpoing to assume he can access the JSON just fine from his own server, just not from jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: if you validate your JSON response here http://jsonlint.com/, this throws an error on line 134: Error: Parse error on line 134:
...ce": 28,   "nome": "PETROBRAS\ DISTR ( 
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: @Dale highly unlikely. The response has no CORS headers at all (wildcard or otherwise), and the code making the request makes no effort to identify the request originator.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan He told us his issue, it isn't with not getting the response

Comment: Yes it is. When blocked by the SOP you'll see the response in the network tab of the console absolutely fine, but the browser will be blocked from accessing that response programmatically.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your crystal ball is obviously better than mine

Comment: You can see that from this fixed jsFiddle (where the loop is through `result.result` instead of `result`, which is OPs code issue): http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2254/

Comment: No it isn't. The OP has posted the response they got. The JSON is invalid.

Comment: No, I just tested and the json is valid. I can access the url and get the json using java in android studio without problem.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Many thanks,  I will go enable CORS headers in my server.  Another question, can I use "post" with ajax and CORS?

Comment: Glad to help, and yes you can

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks again, Now it´s working. Now the problem is with parse json response. I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). Please see at http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2267/

Comment: That's because the response is already deserialized for you by jQuery - doing it again is causing the error. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2268/. Note that the `Unexpected token <` error is being thrown by the google font that you've included in the external resources.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Very Good. Many thanks and happy new year.

Comment: Thanks, and to you!